# Two questions about the approach to an urn-ball problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

An urn contains 3 white balls, 5 red balls and 8 black balls. 2 balls are drawn without replacement. What is the probability of picking out 2 balls of the same color?

a) My first premise is that balls of the same color are indistinguishable

b) My second presime is that when combinations are used the balls are distinguishable

My teacher solved it this way:

$\frac{\binom{3}{2} + \binom{5}{2} + \binom{8}{2}}{\binom{16}{2}} = 0.3417$

My first question is, why using combinations gives a right outcome? Because when combinations are used the balls are distinguishable, when here they are not.

I think that the right approach would be to treat them as undistinguishable:

$\frac{3}{16}  \frac{2}{15} + \frac{5}{16}  \frac{4}{15} + \frac{8}{16} \frac{7}{15} = 0.3417$

My second question is: are there problems like the one above, where using the combination-approach gives a wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second premise is incorrect - distinguishability isn't a factor in choosing combinations or permutations; rather, these choices correspond to caring about *order* or not.

Both of you treat the balls of the same color as distinguishable (and rightly so). Note here that your fraction is essentially the same as your teacher's - multiply by $\frac{2!}{2!}$. This is because, where your teacher counts the number of ways to choose "pairs" of balls, you count the number of ways to choose "ordered pairs" of balls. Since this term to account for order is included in both the numerator and denominator, they end up canceling out and you end up with the same result. For counting problems like this, both approaches will lead you to the correct answer.

Comment: In my case I used the classical definition of probability (cases favorable for the event)/(number of total outcomes possibles). For instance, what's the probability of drawing a white ball? $P(white ball) = 3/16 = 0.1875$. I make no distinction between the three white balls, so I see them as indistiguishable. Am I wrong here?
If I use combinations $\binom{3}{16}= 3/16$ (or permutations) then they are treated as distinguishable. In this case the numbers are the same, but I think that it may be a conceptual difference.

Comment: You treat the white balls as if they were distinguishable - if you treated the balls as distinguishable, then you would have 3 outcomes for a single draw - $\{white,black,red\}$, and your event would be the set containing the single outcome $\{white\}$. Calculating this would give you $\frac{1}{3}$, which is incorrect, since this is not a uniform probability space. Certainly it would work if you assigned the outcomes different probabilities, but then to find these probabilities in the 2-ball case, you would essentially be solving the same problem.

Comment: I meant: If I use combinations $ \frac{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{16}{1}} = 3/16$ (or permutations) then they are treated as distinguishable.

Comment: Yes, and that is as it should be. In order to treat this as a uniform probability space, we have to have that the outcomes all have the same probability - if we treated the balls as indistinguishable, this would not be the case. Even though the balls may all look the same, you can implicitly label them $w_1,w_2,w_3$ to turn it into a uniform space.